# display items in repeater unique per rows?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have repeater I want to display all item like the following output but all item will be duplicate it should be unique per rows.
it should be first display two big columns next row display four samll
columns 
what is my problem with this code I am very beginner in asp.net web forms

[image]

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rp1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsItemsFilter">

             <ItemTemplate>


            <%If counter1 Mod 2 = 1 Then %>

            <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px">


                <%If counter1 Mod 2 = 1 Then %>
                <%for i As Int32 = 1 To 2 %>

            <div style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:150px;border:1px solid #808080;padding:20px">


             <h1>Item <%#Eval("ItemName")%></h1>



            </div>


            <%Next %>

 <%End If %>
            </div>


            <%End If %>


            <br />  <br />

            <%If counter1 Mod 2 = 0 Then %>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px">



                  <%for i As Int32 = 1 To 4 %>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid #808080;padding:20px">


             <h1>Item <%#Eval("ItemName")%></h1>


            </div>


                <%next %>


            </div>
             <%End If %>


                 <%counter1 += 1 %>

 </ItemTemplate>

         </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

In the following code there is no point in the 2nd `If` block as you are just checking the same condition you have checked above it so it will always be true.

```
    <%If counter1 Mod 2 = 1 Then %>
        <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px">
            <%If counter1 Mod 2 = 1 Then %>
```

Items are not unique because you don't increment the counter1 with in the `for` loop. Did you mean to use the loop variable instead?

```
<h1>Item <%=i%></h1>
```

Comment: I am sorry Instead of <h1>Item <%=counter1%></h1> I need to display
<h1>Item <%#Eval("ItemName")%></h1>

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemDataBound function in repeater and also set the value in it according to condition.

```
  <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
         <table border="1">
            <tr>
               <td><b>Product</b></td>
               <td><b>Consumer Rating</b></td>
            </tr>
      </HeaderTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td> <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>' Runat="server"/> </td>
            <td> <asp:Label id="RatingLabel" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Rating") %>' Runat="server"/> </td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>

      <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
      </FooterTemplate>
```

And

```
     public void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
     {
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == 
  ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

         if (((Evaluation)e.Item.DataItem).Rating == "Good") {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("RatingLabel")).Text= "<b>***Good***</b>";
         }
      }
```

}

Like this example you can bind different data.

Comment: I am sorry Sumit, but I need to the output will be like the image in the question.